# Crawling directory and listing all datasources using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I'm editing a script to try and create a list of all datasources within MXD's. I've got the script to crawl the file tree and find all the info, but I would like it to output the data for each layer/datasource on a single line, so it is easy to sort in excel.

Can someone take a look at the code I have so far and let me know how to accomplish that?

```
import arcpy, datetime, os

try:

arcpy.gp.overwriteOutput = True

#Read input parameters from GP dialog
folderPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

#Create an output file
outFile = open(output, "w")

#Loop through each MXD file
count = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folderPath):
    for filename in os.listdir(folderPath):
      fullpath = os.path.join(folderPath, filename)
      if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
        if filename.lower().endswith(".mxd"):

            #Reference MXD
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullpath)
            count = 1

            #Write MXD data to file
            MapDoc = os.path.basename(mxd.filePath)
            MapDocPath = mxd.filePath 

            #Reference each data frame and report data
            DFList = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)
            for df in DFList:
                #Format output values
                if df.description == "": descValue = "None"
                else: descValue = df.description


                #Reference each layer in a data frame
                lyrList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)
                for lyr in lyrList:
                    lyrName = lyr.name 
                    if lyr.supports("dataSource"):
                        lyrDatasource = lyr.dataSource                             
                    else: lyrDatasource = "N/A"

            outFile.write("Map Document, MXD Path, DataFrame List, Description, Layer name, Layer Datasource")
            str = ",";
            seq = (MapDoc, MapDocPath, DFList, descValue, lyrName, lyrDatasource);
            outFile.write(str.join(seq))

            del mxd                      

outFile.close()

#Open resulting text file
os.startfile(output)

#Delete variables that reference data on disk
del folderPath, output, outFile, fullpath

except Exception, e:
import traceback
map(arcpy.AddError, traceback.format_exc().split("\n"))
arcpy.AddError(str(e))
```

The error I recieve when I try to run this is as follows:

```
\MultiMXDReport_crawl.py", line 60, in <module>
outFile.write(str.join(seq))
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected string or Unicode, list found
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'str' object is not callable
Failed to execute (MultiMXDCrawler).
```

Comment: Can you provide a link of where you got the ESRI script from?

Comment: http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=A910AB18-1422-2418-3418-3885D388EF60

Comment: Here is the original script in question: http://pastebin.com/P5NNWbXa

Comment: Pay attention to PEP8 to improve your style http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Yes, please don't lean too much on ESRI examples when learning how to code... very rarely do I see their samples promote good practices as far as coding styles.

Comment: I'm using the script **[blah238](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/753/blah238)** posted, up there, but here in brazil, we have special caracters to write and the code returns an error every time pass by it. If i have a layer in the mxd with "á é í ç" or others, it stops with the error: "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc1' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)" I know, for example, that **\xc1** means **Á**. But i dont know how to deal with the code, to keep running the script. import arcpy, os, csv def main(folder, outputfile): with open(outputfile, "wb") as f

Comment: Hi @raphael, could you please ask this as a [new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead of posting it as an _answer_? You can always include a link to this post in your question to show you did some research :)

Answer (score 12):

Two main problems I see with your script:

One is you need to indent properly. Indentation is part of the syntax and logic in Python, and because your `seq` variable assignment and `outFile.write` call is declared outside of the innermost loop (where you iterate through each layer in each data frame) you will not get the desired result.

The other is that you reference a list variable in your `seq` assignment and then attempt to join the sequence elements. This is not possible because `join` expects string or unicode objects for the sequence elements. Therefore you will first need to convert your `DFList` variable to a string by joining again, or more likely what you want is to just reference the current `df` variable's name property.

Stylistically and practically I would consider breaking your script up into functions, as well as using the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module to generate a CSV file. Consider using a [generator function](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) to produce the rows of data you want to send to the CSV writer.

Here is a version of the script that uses the `csv` module and a generator function:

```
import arcpy, os, csv

def main(folder, outputfile):
    with open(outputfile, "wb") as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        header = ("Map Document", "MXD Path", "DataFrame Name", "DataFrame Description", "Layer name", "Layer Datasource")
        w.writerow(header)
        rows = crawlmxds(folder)
        w.writerows(rows)

def crawlmxds(folder):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
        for f in files:
            if f.lower().endswith(".mxd"):
                mxdName = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
                mxdPath = os.path.join(root, f)
                mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdPath)
                dataframes = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)
                for df in dataframes:
                    dfDesc = df.description if df.description != "" else "None"
                    layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)
                    for lyr in layers:
                        lyrName = lyr.name
                        lyrDatasource = lyr.dataSource if lyr.supports("dataSource") else "N/A"
                        seq = (mxdName, mxdPath, df.name, dfDesc, lyrName, lyrDatasource);
                        yield seq
                del mxd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    folderPath = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\DeveloperKit10.0\Samples\data" # or arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    output = r"c:\GISData\mxdcrawler.csv" # or arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    main(folderPath, output)
```

Comment: This worked for me, but it does not allow for any "special characters". You need to add .encode('utf-8') to any string variables that might contain anything beyond ASCII values.

Answer (score 4):

1. While not strictly a reserved word, "str" is the name of a built in python type (and function). Don't use it as a variable name.

   ```
   >>> print str, str(1234)
   <type 'str'> 1234
   >>> str='somestring'
   >>> print str, str(1234)
   somestringTraceback (most recent call last):
     File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
   TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
   ```
2. DFList is a list, lists (within lists) can't be joined, only strings can.  i.e.

   ```
   >>> print ','.join(['astring',['alist','withstrings']])
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
   TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, list found

   >>> print ','.join(['astring','anotherstring','laststring'])
   astring,anotherstring,laststring
   ```

   If you need to join a list of lists, use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

   ```
   >>> lst=['1',['2','3'],'4']
   >>> print ','.join(['somestring'.join(l) for l in lst])
   1,2somestring3,4
   ```
3. DFList is a list of dataframe objects. It doesn't really make sense trying to write that out to a file:

   ```
   >>> print DFList
   [<DataFrame object at 0x60f48d0[0x6102d40]>, <DataFrame object etc...]>]
   ```
4. Also, I think you probably intended to write just the name and description of the dataframe that a given layer is in, not all dataframes in the mxd, so the following code makes a bit more sense (though could definitely be improved as per other answers in this thread):

   ```
   import arcpy, datetime, os

   arcpy.gp.overwriteOutput = True

   #Read input parameters from GP dialog
   folderPath = 'd:/temp'#arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
   output = 'd:/temp/test.txt' #arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

   #Create an output file
   outFile = open(output, "w")
   #==== Moved to before loop so you only write the headers once, note linebreak '\n' character
   outFile.write("Map Document,MXD Path,DataFrame Name,DataFrame Description,Layer name,Layer Datasource\n")

   #Loop through each MXD file
   for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folderPath):
       for file in files: # files is a list of files in the current directory
           if file.lower().endswith(".mxd"):
               fullpath = os.path.join(root, file) # root is the current directory
               #Reference MXD
               mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullpath)

               #Write MXD data to file
               MapDoc = os.path.basename(mxd.filePath)
               MapDocPath = mxd.filePath

               #Reference each data frame and report data
               DFList = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)
               for df in DFList:
                   #Format output values
                   if df.description == "": descValue = "None"
                   else: descValue = df.description
                   #==== Note the new descName variable
                   descName=df.name

                   #Reference each layer in a data frame
                   lyrList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)
                   for lyr in lyrList:
                       lyrName = lyr.name
                       if lyr.supports("dataSource"):
                           lyrDatasource = lyr.dataSource
                       else: lyrDatasource = "N/A"
                       #==== Got rid of DFList and inserted descName instead
                       seq = (MapDoc, MapDocPath, descName, descValue, lyrName, lyrDatasource);
                       #==== Got rid of "str" variable and just used a string literal - ','
                       outFile.write(','.join(seq)+'\n')
               del mxd
   outFile.close()
   ```

Comment: I made some small changes to your script to get it working -- os.walk was not being utilized properly, and it's still pretty ugly but it does run.

Comment: It's not my script :) Feel free to completely refactor it if you like, haha. I'm itching to, but that would defeat the purpose of what I was trying to show with the minor changes to @Chris' code.

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I did any python (I mostly use C# these days) however just a quick glance at your code tells me that your trying to join an array of strings in your sequence.

Essentially your taking:

```
[string1][string2][string3]
```

and expecting it to behave like

```
string1
```

or to be more specific:

```
[[field1][field2][field3]]
[[field1][field2][field3]]
[[field1][field2][field3]]
```

when what you need is

```
[[field1][field2][field3]]
```

being repeated each time so that you end up with

```
field1,field2,field3
.
.
.
field1,field2,field3
```

where you have your `seq = (...)` line, you essentially want to loop over that sequence like so

**repeat loop for each line of
  Mapdoc,MapdocPath,DFList,descvalue,lyrname,lyrDatasource concatenating each field with a ,
  write that line to a file with a newline
end loop when no more lines left**

at the moment your simply trying to

**take each array element
  join each array element with , as if each element was a string
end loop when all array elements have been joined
write entire long string in one go to file**

by the way I know this is a bit of a strange answer, but as I say it's a long time since I've done any python and I don't have an interpreter to hand to test any code, I can see from the program flow though what's going on, and if you split your bigger array into lots of smaller arrays, then join each of those smaller ones in turn to form a single line that should solve your problem.

Comment: Would the down voter care to explain why the down vote instead of scurrying back off into the woodwork like a coward?

Answer (score -2):

I've spent quite a bit of time on this problem.  I'll refer you to my script on GitHub :

https://github.com/GeospatialDaryl/SHC_DataSpider_v1p0

It wrestles with a lot of the issues above.

In particular -

- The os.walk approach is sound, and you can set up simple file-system level matching to identify file-system objects (like picking out .shp).  However, this won't be able to introspect file or personal geodatabase, and lots of file system architecture metadata (as in, what folders contain which data) will be lost.  A better approach is to make an inventory of 'workspaces' (defined as locations that contain datasets) and then inventory those using an inventory function.

  - What is metadata?  I think the most powerful output from an approach like this is to render a feature class of extent rectangles for all the data sets.  That way, you get geographic information about the location of the data on your system.  Other attributes can be linked to this key geometry.
  - Finally, the biggest issue is what data are referenced by which maps, and where are they?  What's the most popular data on the system?  A relational database approach is a robust way to capture the information querable off the arcpy.Describe object.

Comment: Welcome to the site @Daryl.  Please update the post to describe what the link is describing.  Otherwise, if the link becomes defunct, so to does the answer.  More details on GIS SE answers can be found at our help center: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help